# `attr('id')` is failing inside my `each()` function

Tags: jquery

jQuery

```
var myID = new Array("A1","B2");
$.each($(".tab"), function(index,value) {

var id = value.attr('id'); //error here :(

if(id == myID[index])
id.addClass('sel');

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab" id="A1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="A2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="A3"></div>

<div class="tab" id="B1"></div>
<div class="tab" id="B2"></div>
<div class="tab" id="B3"></div>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is, I want to add class to html which have matched with array `myID`. The code I have above throws an error on the line `var id = value.attr('id');`.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$.fn.each](http://api.jquery.com/each) instead of [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) - either one will let you refer to the DOM element with the `this` keyword or the second argument (`value`)

```
var myID = new Array("A1","B2");
$(".tab").each( function(index, value) {
    this == value; //true
    var id = this.id; //Property access is faster than attr or prop

    if(id == myID[index])
        $(this).addClass('sel'); //addClass gets called on a jQuery object, not a string

});
```

Alternatively, you can iterate over your array and add the class directly:

```
var myID = ["A1", "B2"]; //or new Array(...);
$.each(myID, function(index, value) {
    $("#"+value).addClass("sel");
});
```

Comment: `$.fn.each` maps to `$.each` [under the hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7/src/core.js#L252), so there's no harm in using it.  In fact, it's even a very small optimization.

Comment: @AndyE Good catch.  I still prefer `fn` because it looks cleaner, but I guess it is up to the OP.

Comment: yeah it's a personal preference thing, I go with `.fn.each` most of the time for the same reason.  It's not worth worrying about for a micro-optimization in most scenarios tbh.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't add the class. Weird, anything that getting called inside `if(id == myID[index])` is not working include alert. why is that so? thank you

Comment: @cicakman `index` is the zero-based index in the selected set.  Do you want to check `this.id` against every element in `myID`?

Comment: Actually, what i want do is, to make that whatever in myID(produced by php from database) to be added class of sel. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`$.each` iterates over the numeric properties of the jQuery object, which are actually plain DOM elements.  Change it to

```
var id = value.id;
```

and use

```
$(value).addClass('sel');
```

to add the class.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers fail to address the other problem, `id.addClass('sel');`.

`id` will be a primitive type, and hence will not have an `addClass` method.

```
var myID = new Array("A1","B2");
$.each($(".tab"), function(index,value)
{
    var id = $(value).attr('id'); //change here
    if(id == myID[index])
        $(value).addClass('sel'); //also, a change here
}
```

Comment: does not work. I tried to alert inside `if(id == myID[index])`, alert is not showing up. What could the problem be ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var myID = new Array("A1","B2");
$.each($(".tab"), function(index,value) {

var id = $(this).attr('id');

if(id == myID[index]){
      id.addClass('sel');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = value.attr('id'); //error here :(
```

should be

```
var id = $(value).attr('id'); //error here :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from not wapping "value" in a jquery wrapper.

```
id = $(value).attr ("id");
```

Or you can bypass jquery and do:

```
 id = value.id;
```

And adding a class with jquery requires:

```
$(value).addClass("sel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you might just do

```
var myID = new Array("A1","B2");
for (var id in myID) {
  $("#" + id).addClass("sel");
}
```